# Using JAR Files

Tags: java, jar

So I'm still a noob in Java and I'm experimenting around with a few things.

I recently created a .jar file for my class using `jar cvf <name>.jar <source files>` and then used that jar to compile my driver class (`javac -cp <name>.jar Driver.java`) though how do I now run that class using the jar?

I've tried the following 2 commands:
`java Driver` and,
`java -cp <name>.jar Driver`.

The first gives me a `NoClassDefFoundError` for the class used, whereas the latter just gave me a single line error.

> Error: Could not find or load man class Driver

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible I'm confusing this for something else?
I'm trying to do as much as I can without the use of any IDE.

Comment: Does your Driver class contain the main method?

Comment: @Kayaman yes. I've initialized everything correctly as well.

Comment: Driver is in a package ?

Comment: Uh, did you compile the class before you put it in the jar?

Comment: No @dwursteisen and yes Kayaman

Comment: So you have a jar of classes and a class outside of the jar, and you wish to run the class that is outside of the jar file? If so, see `tomasz77's` answer. Replace `classes` with the directory your Driver.class is in, and if you're on Linux, use `:` instead of `;` as the separator.

Comment: Ahh cheers @Kayaman. Didn't quite understand what tomasz77 meant by `classes` but this seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put jar file and compiler output into classpath and specify main class:

```
java -classpath "<name.jar>;classes" Driver
```

EDIT (thanks to Kayaman):
If you are running command from linux/unix you have to use ":" as separator (in Windows works ";"). "classes" is a path to folder containing compiler output.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an executable jar ( jar which contain a class with the main method) you should tell the jar which is the mainClass to be executed and for that you should create a file called   'Manifest.mf'.

The file should contain this:

```
Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass
```

And when creating the jar you should use this to include your manifest:

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.mf MyPackage/*.class
```

And for launching your jar :

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Comment: Not an executable jar. Probably should have clarified.